# How to create the below described method involving Lists and arrays

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and have been given the task to create a method that takes a list of string arrays as an argument and allows you to give as many arrays as you want and the method returns all the arrays as one single List. I know the keyword params will not work in this instance and I know ToList and ToArray. What I'm having trouble with is the argument part. How is it possible to give as many "arrays" as you want?

Comment: The type of "a list of string arrays" is `List<string[]>` - accept an argument of that type.

Comment: Correct, but will it let you give as many as you want?

Comment: @billy_caul Until you run out of resources, yes.

Comment: Yes. Here's the syntax: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9uedjM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<string[]>` is data structure which can hold as many arrays as you want. It can be passed as parameter to function.

```
//Parameter listOfArrays contains 0-n arrays of strings
public List<string> FlattenLists(List<string[]> listOfArrays)
{
    var returnValue = new List<string>();
    foreach (var array in listOfArrays)
    {
        returnValue.AddRange(array);

    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I named my method as `FlattenLists` as it takes 0-n arrays of strings and returns one list containing all strings.

Here is example as how you use this:

```
var listOfArrays = new List<string[]>();
listOfArrays.Add(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
listOfArrays.Add(new string[] { "value3", "value4" });
listOfArrays.Add(new string[] { "value5", "value6" });

var singleList = FlattenLists(listOfArrays);
//singleList now contains 6 items ("value1"-"value6")
```

I used here both [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) class and `string[]` - array. Most notable difference between these two is that `List` size can be modified run-time but array size is fixed.

[Generic collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netframework-4.8) List is flexible data structure and you can make even deeper hierarchies with it (for example `List<List<List<string>>>`).

Comment: You're not really helping OP by doing their homework for them. This doesn't even explicitly answer the question asked: "How is it possible to give as many "arrays" as you want?"

Comment: It absolutely answers that question. And the answer is, with a list

Comment: I think the OP answered his own question just didn't see it

Comment: Now it explicitly answers the question. Good edit. I still would have left the implementation out, but no big deal.

Comment: Thanks for comments.. I added some data structure basics to answer which I think can help with C# learning

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.